# how to read and write TermDocumentMatrix in r?

Tags: r, nlp, term-document-matrix

I made wordcloud using a csv file in R. I used `TermDocumentMatrix` method in the `tm` package. Here is my code:

```
csvData <- read.csv("word", encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Encoding(csvData$content) <- "UTF-8"
# useSejongDic() - KoNLP package
nouns <- sapply(csvData$content, extractNoun, USE.NAMES = F)
#create Corpus
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(nouns))

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
# remove numbers
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
#remove StopWord 
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)

#create Matrix
TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(2,5)))

m <- as.matrix(TDM)
```

This process seemed to take too much time. I think `extractNoun` is what accounts for too much time being spent. To make the code more time-efficient, I want to save the resulting TDM as a file. When I read this saved file, can I use `m <- as.matrix(saved TDM file)` completely? Or, is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but I've used NLP sometimes.

I do use `parSapply` from `parallel` package. Here's the documentation http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf

`parallel` comes with R base and this is a silly using example:

```
library(parallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterExport(cl, "base")

base <- 2
parSapply(cl, as.character(2:4), 
          function(exponent){
            x <- as.numeric(exponent)
            c(base = base^x, self = x^x)
          })
```

So, parallelize `nouns <- sapply(csvData$content, extractNoun, USE.NAMES = F)` and it will be faster :)

Comment: Could you answer one more question? If you don't mind.
I use `parallel` as you said. But This seemed to bring a huge memory leak. So I use `gc()` a temporary measure. Have you ever had this experience? If so, Is there a way?

Comment: I didn't see that. It depends on the system. If you use windows maybe `cl<-makeCluster(no_cores, type="FORK")` but I haven't used Windows since XP

Comment: I tried `cl<-makeCluster(no_cores, type="FORK")` to solve my problem.
But It's not worked. 
So, I think I need to find a way to manage memory...
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Hi. Maybe its better to stay with the method I posted yesterday that worked. Otherwise, maybe is ok to compile R to use the 100% of your architecture.

Comment: I think it would be better. 
I'll stay with the method as you posted.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have a call to several *library(tm)* commands which can also easily be parallelized.  For *library tm* this functionality was updated in March 2017, a month after your question.

In the *new features* section of the release notes for *library tm* version 0.7 (2017-03-02) it is indicated:

> tm_parLapply() is now internally used for the parallelization of transformations, filters, and term-document matrix construction. The preferred parallelization engine can be registered via tm_parLapply_engine(). The default is to use no parallelization (instead of mclapply (package parallel) in previous versions).

To set up parallelization for the tm commands the following has worked for me:

```
library(parallel)
cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores)   # use cores-1 if you want to do anything else on the PC.
tm_parLapply_engine(cl)
## insert your commands for create corpus, 
## tm_map and TermDocumentMatrix commands here
tm_parLapply_engine(NULL)
stopCluster(cl)
```

If you have function that you are applying through a tm_map content transformer, you will need to use clusterExport to pass that function to the parallelized environment before the tm_map(MyCorpus, content_transformer(clean)) command.   EG. passing my clean function to the environment.

```
clusterExport(cl, "clean")
```

One last comment, keep an eye on your memory usage.  If your computer starts paging memory out to disk the CPU is no longer the critical path and all the parallelization won't make a difference.