# R, is there any way that make a termdocumentmatrix by using multiple core?

Tags: parallel-processing, tm, term-document-matrix

Hello.

Is there any way that make a termdocumentmatrix by using mutiple cores, parallel processing ?

Or to get more fast result, can i use some packages like parallel, h2o, or others?

someone help me please. 
thanks.

Comment: Check out the **quanteda** package. It does some parallelisation in splitting and hashing tokens, and while the dfm construction is not currently parallelized, many other functions are. (And the dfm construction is still super fast.)

Comment: thank you for your answer. i will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um. i found very very good information at below link.

[how to read and write TermDocumentMatrix in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103676/how-to-read-and-write-termdocumentmatrix-in-r)

and, when i used parallel and tm packages, 
i have to set my variables, functions, libraries like below. 
(If not, errors occur.)

---

clusterExport(cl, list("josa1", "josa2","josa3","josa4")) # for variables, functions

clusterEvalQ(cl, library(stringr)) # for libraries

---

It works. 
Thanks.